# Searching for a name in PHP

Tags: php, search, mysqli, pdo

How do you search for a name, or something like a keyword and expected a many results?

Like, when you search **Mark**,
You're expecting to have like this:
*Mark* Zuckerberg
*Mark* Hamil
*Mark* Fischbach
...

But when I do the query, it only display one for me.

I've tried to use many different SQL clauses and other stuffs, but still gives me a one result out of this. By the way, I am using ***PDO*** as my database handler.

This is my codes:

```
<?php
require_once '../../assets/conn.db.php';
require_once '../../assets/init.php';
require_once '../../assets/main.func.php';

if($_POST){
  $namesearch = $_POST['name'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `student_info` WHERE username LIKE ? OR username LIKE ?";
  $checkstmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $checkstmt->execute(array("%{$namesearch}%","%{$namesearch}%"));
  $result = $checkstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if($result){
    echo "
    <table border='1' class='text-align: center'>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{$result['name']}</td>
        <td>{$result['phone']}</td>
        <td>{$result['address']}</td>
        <td>{$result['username']}</td>
        <td><a href='grades.php?user=".$result['StudentID']."'>+</a> Add Grades</td>
      </tr>
    </table> <br>
    ";
  }
}

 ?>

<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Search for a student">
  <input type="submit" value="Search!">
</form>
```

Comment: you only fetch one (the "next") row. You'll need to loop and fetch them all. like `while ($result = $checkstmt->fetch(...) {...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns all results you need, but you only fetch a single data. Mr. K. O. Rolling gave you the general idea of how to iterate the results, let's apply that to your exact problem:

```
require_once '../../assets/conn.db.php';
require_once '../../assets/init.php';
require_once '../../assets/main.func.php';

if($_POST){
  $namesearch = $_POST['name'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `student_info` WHERE username LIKE ? OR username LIKE ?";
  $checkstmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $checkstmt->execute(array("%{$namesearch}%","%{$namesearch}%"));
  $result = $checkstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo "
    <table border='1' class='text-align: center'>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>";
  while($data = $checkstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "
      <tr>
        <td>{$result['name']}</td>
        <td>{$result['phone']}</td>
        <td>{$result['address']}</td>
        <td>{$result['username']}</td>
        <td><a href='grades.php?user=".$data['StudentID']."'>+</a> Add Grades</td>
      </tr>
    ";
  }
  echo "</table> <br>";
}
```

The code is untested. In the `while` on each iteration you initialize `$data` with the current element and evaluate it logically. If there is no more element, then it will be falsey and the cycle will exit. Otherwise it will get the item and write the `tr`.

Further improvement:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `student_info` WHERE username LIKE ? OR username LIKE ?";
  $checkstmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $checkstmt->execute(array("%{$namesearch}%","%{$namesearch}%"));
```

Notice here that you check the same thing twice, which is not very optimal. Improvement:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `student_info` WHERE username LIKE ?";
  $checkstmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $checkstmt->execute(array("%{$namesearch}%"));
```

Also, it is wise to use a column list instead of * in the select.

Comment: Is `foreach` can be a substitute for a while, and is there a benchmark or performance difference with a `foreach` vs a `while` loop?

Comment: To be able to use a foreach you need to have a set to iterate. In this case you do not have such a set, but you can get one by using fetchAll. If you do that, you will be able to iterate the result, see: http://php.net/manual/ro/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: @astronomicalXoom mainly the difference comes from differences done inside the cycle. In our case foreach and while would to the same thing essentially, therefore the difference is minuscule if any.

Answer (score 4):

The sql query is correct, to output all elements of the result you have to iterate over $result.

Example:

```
while($data = $result->fetch_array())
{
  echo $result["name"];
}
```